# Login with 2 different tables from MySql and they have their own different windows form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

I want to login in 1 login form for 2 different tables from database and every table has it's own windows form.

I have 2 tables from MySql

- SECRETARY_REGISTRATION
- REGISTRATION

They have their own windows form

- SECRETARY_REGISTRATION has HomePageSecretary
- REGISTRATION has HomePagePhysician

I only have 1 login form for both and it has the Username textbox and Password textbox and the button for Login only.

Please help me. Thank you. :)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = ArlineCuachon\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = CDSS;
                                            Integrated Security = true;");
        string query = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRATION WHERE RUsername = '" + UsernameLogin.Text.Trim() + "' AND RPassword = '" + PasswordLogin.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                HomePagePhysician home = new HomePagePhysician();
                home.ShowDialog();

            }

            else

            {

                MessageBox.Show("You have entered wrong username or password!");

            }
        string query = "SELECT * FROM SECRETARY_REGISTRATION WHERE SUsername = '" + UsernameLogin.Text.Trim() + "' AND SPassword = '" + PasswordLogin.Text.Trim() + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dtbl1 = new DataTable();
        sda1.Fill(dtbl1);
        if (dtbl1.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            HomePageSecretary home = new HomePageSecretary();
            home.ShowDialog();
        }

        else

        {

            MessageBox.Show("You have entered wrong username or password!");

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write the code two times, you can check in both the table with a single call like following query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3...ColN, 'Registartion' as TypeOfLogin FROM REGISTRATION
    UNION
    SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3...ColN, 'Secretary Registration' as TypeOfLogin FROM SECRETARY_REGISTRATION 
) T
WHERE T.SUsername  = 'UserName' AND T.SPassword ='Somepassword'
```

To differentiate the type of user, you can use the column `TypeOfLogin`, if the value is `Registartion` load `HomePagePhysician` form else load `HomePageSecretary`  form

There are other critical issues in you code like you are building dynamic queries, ideally you need to use parameters to avoid any **SQL Injection** attacks.

Read more about SQL Injections [here](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

To read about how to use command parameters, you can read [this](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. :)